# Microsoft Band Web Tile manifast.json using regex

Tags: json, regex, microsoft-band

Microsoft Band Web Tile has manifast.json. Based on the documentation, https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20Web%20Tile%20Documentation.pdf. I've added regular expression rather than plain string value.

```
"notifications": [
    {
      "condition": "{{_1_description}} contains /[0-3][0-9].[0-9]+ MPH/g",
      "title": "{{_1_title}}",
      "body": "{{_1_description}}"
    }
  ]
```

With regex being correct, the web tile is not running 'condition' property. Has anybody was able to insert regex under notification condition?

Comment: `contains` usually does not allow regex. Are you sure the docs mention that you can?